# Modifying shortest path to get a min-cost path

Tags: algorithm, graph, theory, graph-algorithm

If we modify the shortest path problem such that the cost of a path between two vertices is the maximum of the costs of the edges on it, then for any pair of vertices u and v,
the path between them that follows a minimum-cost spanning tree is a min-cost path.

How can I prove this approach is true? It makes sense but I am not sure. Does anyone know if this algorithm exists in the literature? Is there a name for it?

Comment: The shortest-path problem *is* the min-cost problem, where "cost" is defined as a distance.  Are you talking about a problem where there is both distance and some *other* cost, which is the one you want to minimize?  Traffic/Driving is such a problem, where you may have two costs: distance and time. A shorter but busier street has a lower distance cost but a higher time cost, and you can minimize for one or the other, or some weighted combination of the two. (Not entirely relevant to constructing a proof)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some basic facts of MST (that are usually discussed in the correctness proof for Prim's & Kruskal's algorithms). The one that matters now is that

**Lema 1:**

> Given a graph cut (a partitioning of the vertices into two
>   disjoint sets) the edge in the MST connecting the two parts will be
>   the cheapest of the edges connecting the two parts.

(The proof is straighfoward, if there were a cheaper edge we would be able to easily contruct a cheaper spanning tree)

We can now prove that the paths in a MST are all min-cost paths if you consider the maximum-cost:

Take any two vertices `s` and `t` in `G` and the path `p` that connects them in a MST of G. Now let `uv` be the most expensive edge in this path. We can describe a graph cut over this edge, with one partition with the vertices on the `u` side of the MST and the other partition with the vertices on the `v` side. We know that any path connecting `s` and `t` must pass this cut, therefore we can determine that the cost of any path from `s` to `t` must be at least the cost of the cheapest edge on this cut. But Lemma 1 tells us that uv is the cheapest edge on this cut so `p` must be a min-cost path.

Comment: There is always a minimum spanning tree (there are a finite number of possible trees - a subset of them must be minimal) and there is always a path between any two nodes in any spanning tree (because the tree spans all the vertices). The proof then basically says that those paths in the MSTs are also min-cost paths if the cost is determined by maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you mentioned is discussed in detail in literatures that discuss the relationship between Prim's algorithm and Dijkstra's algorithm, as usual wikipedia is a good place to start your research:

> The process that underlies [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is similar to the greedy process used in [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm). Prim's purpose is to find a minimum spanning tree that connects all nodes in the graph; Dijkstra is concerned with only the lowest cost path beteen two nodes.